# Complete list of methods of NSView that must not be used when view is layer backed or hosts user's layer

Tags: cocoa, core-animation, osx-snow-leopard, osx-lion

I'm looking for a complete list of methods that must not be used when a view is layer backed or hosts user's layer, because passing them to an instance may lead app to crash or they just do nothing. Also, I'd like to know which methods only make sense when view is layer backed.

The target platform is 10.6+, so if there are differences between 10.6 and 10.7, they're welcome too.

Comment: What makes you think that there are any? Examples?

Comment: E.g. `-drawRect:` as well as `-setNeedsDisplay:` have no sense when view wants layer. I believe methods to manipulate subviews are also have no sense when view hosts a layer.

Answer (score 2):

```
printOp = [NSPrintOperation printOperationWithView:view printInfo: printInfo];
```

doesn't work for layer-backed NSViews. You have to render the target view into an image view and use this for printing.